# Replace string in file before uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have following terraform script that uploads bunch of files to AWS S3

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "website_files" {
  for_each      = fileset(var.client_upload_directory, "**/*.*")
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.ada-website.bucket
  key           = replace(each.value, var.client_upload_directory, "")
  source        = "${var.client_upload_directory}${each.value}"
}
```

Is there a way to replace one string with another in file content before upload? I did try use `content` instead of `source` - something like this

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "website_files" {
  for_each      = fileset(var.client_upload_directory, "**/*.*")
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.ada-website.bucket
  key           = replace(each.value, var.client_upload_directory, "")
  content       = replace(file("${var.client_upload_directory}${each.value}"), "string 1", "string 2"))
}
```

but the drawback is - `plan` or `apply` displays content of entire file - which can be quite large. Also ideally this replacement should be applied only to one file out of the set, the rest should upload as is with that file skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this outside of terraform, via shell script.